# My Ionic App uploads oictures when runned from the server on my browser but won't upload pictures when isntalled in my phone

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-native

So I was building an app as an assignment from school which is supposed to upload pictures and forms to a server. On the broswer when using "ionic serve" the images upload just fine. But on the phone after installation after selecting the image you wish to upload it loads and loads forever and the image is not uploaded

function that takes in the image

```
async UploadImage(){
    const image= await Camera.getPhoto({
      quality: 90,
      allowEditing: false,
      resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
      source: CameraSource.Photos,
    });

    console.log(image);

    if(image){
      const loading= await this.loadingController.create();
      await loading.present();

      let result= await this.formUpload.uploadImage(image);
      loading.dismiss();

      console.log(result[1])

      if(result[0]==false){
        const toaster= await this.toastController.create({
          position: 'bottom',
          message: "Image not uploaded",
          color: 'danger',
          duration: 3000,
        });
        toaster.present();
      }else{
        this.images.push(result[1])
      }
    }
  }
```

function that uploads the image and returns the url

```
async uploadImage(cameraFile: Photo){
        let now=new Date()
        const user=this.auth.currentUser;
        const path= `uploads/${user.uid}/formImage${now}.png`;
        const storageref= ref(this.fireStorage, path);

        try {
            await uploadString(storageref, cameraFile.base64String, 'base64');
            let imageUrl: string;
            imageUrl =await getDownloadURL (storageref);
            console.log(imageUrl)
            return [true, imageUrl];
        } catch (error) {
            return error
        }
    }
```

On the browser the image uploads perfectly well but on the phone just loads and loads and loads and nothing is done

Comment: Is it possible that the server has CORS restrictions? Take a look at this Github repository to see if it helps https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-proxy-example

Comment: The thing is I used but Firebase. I recently added other functions to write to and read from and they work just not that one